# How to update django user profile information from a form?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I'm creating a web application to track my friends personal bets amongst eachother.. I have added a UserBalance value to the user model, but now I want superuser/admins to be able to update that upon submitting a form.

[List of all bets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d0qHQ.png)
[Leaderboard with user balances](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CqwGS.png)

How would I go about making it so the form in last column of first screenshot will update both bettor's balances?

accounts models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

# Create your models here.
    
class UserBalance(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    balance = models.IntegerField(default=0)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_balance(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        UserBalance.objects.create(user=instance)
```

I assume I need to add a method somewhere to take the winner/loser form info and then change the corresponding user's balances but I'm not sure where to do that or how